# Frida - Java.perform() is crashing the app

Tags: android, security, mobile, reverse-engineering, frida

I just started to use Frida recently, and I am trying to change a boolean value from false to true in an Android app that I made.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView helloWorld = findViewById(R.id.FirstTextView);
        if(flag()){
            helloWorld.setText("I am in :)");
        }
    }
    public boolean flag(){
         return false;
    }
}
```

So, I created a simple script that will change the value of the function flag() and it will return true.

```
if(Java.available){
    console.log("Java is available")
    setTimeout(function() { // avoid java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
        console.log("\n Frida");
        Java.perform(function(){
            console.log("\n Inside the app");
            var hook = Java.use("com.example.helloworld.MainActivity");
            console.log("info: hooking target class");
            hook.flag.implementation = function() {
                console.log("info: entered target method");
                return ture;
            }
        });
    }, 0);
}
else {
    console.log("java is not available")
}
```

When I run the script with the following command
`$ frida -U -f com.example.helloworld -l script.js --no-pause` the app crashes before the script enter the function Java.perform()

[image: script result]

[image: emulator]

I Killed the app and restarted Frida and still got the same result
[image]

I ran logcat to see the why the app is crashing and got the following

```
06-25 14:22:04.918  1635  9352 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager: Exception thrown during pause
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:727)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:867)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2907)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2763)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2755)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11971)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11867)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12556)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:12063)
06-25 14:22:04.919  1635  9352 W ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
```

From the crash it seems that process is no longer exist that why it crash. So I tried to ran the app first and then attache to it PID using the command `frida -U -p 9376 -l script.js --no-pause`

[image: script result]

This time the app didn't crash, but it did not change the value of the flag function

Comment: Please do not post code in screenshots. Code is text and you can simply insert it into your question and apply the "Code sample" format on it. In any way you are trying to hook the package `com.example.helloworld` which of course does not work. You can only hook classes like your MainActivity.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for the advice I have edited my question, but the error still there, the third log in my script is not printed to the screen.

Comment: Most likely because `onCreate` is executed before you attach Frida and therefore `flag` is not called and the hook does not trigger.

Comment: So what do you recommend to do?

Comment: Kill the appp exit Frida and restart everything using the frida command-line command shown in your picture (again a screenshot).

Comment: I did as you asked, please check the new picture

Comment: You should check logcat why the app crashes.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, the logcat was very handy and I was able to progress a little bit. kindly check the changes that I made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216634/discussion-between-waleed-and-robert).

Comment: I see ``return ture;`` in your code, is it a typo on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes, it is a typo, but the log statement before it is not printing out, which means that it didn't reach it yet. @Jean-BaptisteMartin